# Java Selenium - Select an Element from Google Maps Live traffic view

Tags: java, google-maps, selenium

In the image attached, I want to select/click any of the elements inside map. Lets say Road Blocked or Crashes or Construction in progress. How do I select these elements. In the developer tool .I don't see any html elements corresponding to this. URL for below image is :

> https://www.google.com/maps/@51.5159523,-0.1519764,13z/data=!5m1!1e1

[image: Below is the image]

Answer (score 2):

You don't see any HTML elements because the map is a [Canvas](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp). I think the only way can you can interact with a canvas is to click on specific coordinates using a [Selenium Action](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html).